# Get SublimeClang to work on OSX 10.9 Mavericks / Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, sublimetext2, osx-mavericks

I'm using Sublime Text 2 with SublimeClang. After upgraded to Mavericks / Xcode 5, SublimeClang stopped working. Static analyzer that calls command line `clang` still works fine, but the background diagnostic keeps complaining that it can't find `iostream`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I ended up solving it by re-installing the Xcode command line tools.

I ran this command in my terminal:

```
xcode-select --install
```

After that, SublimeClang seemed to work again.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Apple had updated `clang` in Xcode 5, and they have also dismissed the `/usr/include` path. For some mysterious reason, the new `libclang.dylib` in Xcode 5 does not recognize the default include path; it still tries to search `/usr/include` and `usr/include/c++` for system header.

After checking with `cpp -v`, I've figured out that these include paths shall be included in the argument list when calling `clang_parseTranslationUnit`:

```
-I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/
-I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/c++/v1
-I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/5.0/include
-I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include
```

I can't put those arguments in the the "options" section of `SublimeClang.sublime-settings`, since it will be overridden by `sublimeclang_options` of each project. So I added these inside the `additional_language_options` section.

Now SublimeClang can finally work, not an ideal solution though. Anyone have better solutions ?