# Sublime text 2 after Mavericks update on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, sublimetext2, osx-mavericks

I have problem with Sublime Text 2 and C++, after Mavericks (10.9) OS X update when i complie it cant find librarys and gives me an error

```
 error: 'endl' was not declared in this scope
```

and the same is with cout, cin and I am prety sure its with all the iostream functions
and yes I did include iostream

Comment: Have a look at [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980759/xcode-select-active-developer-directory-error-on-osx-mavericks) and see if it helps. (You did update XCode, right?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue with this where SublimeClang's diagnostics couldn't find any libraries (iostream, string, etc..) after upgrading to Mavericks.

The solution for me was to reinstall Xcode command line tools.

```
xcode-select --install
```

From what you've said I'd suggest giving this a shot. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561616/get-sublimeclang-to-work-on-osx-10-9-mavericks-xcode-5)